# can't figure out the query which is using MOD function into account

Tags: java, mysql

I am going through the following code in Java for SQL Query:

```
String QueryString =      " SELECT "  
                                        + "     RXCallDetailId_int, "
                                        + "     DTSID_int, "
                                        + " FROM " 
                                        + "     mytable "
                                        + " WHERE "
                                        + "     StatusId_ti = " + ESID                        
                                        + "     AND RXCallDetailId_int MOD " + NumberOfResultsThreads + " = " +  CurrModValue;
```

After checking the database table, I see `RXCallDetailId_int` starting value as `241712` and last value as `305382`   based on the `StatusId_ti = -15`

I have the variables defined as follows:

```
 private static int NumberOfResultsThreads = 10;

   private int CurrModValue = 10;

   private static int ESID = -15;
```

I am wondering, what will be the output of the line  `AND RXCallDetailId_int MOD " + NumberOfResultsThreads + " = " +  CurrModValue;`

look like? Unable to imagine with a MOD function being used there because MySQL uses MOd function differently like: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

Please clarify

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The result of `N MOD M` will always be in the range `[0, M)`. Thus, `N MOD M <> M` always. Because `NumberOfResultsThreads == CurrModValue`, your result set is empty.

Comment: So, Mathematically, in my case, starting from first value of `RXCallDetailId_int` , my query will look something like, if we substitute the values ,`AND 24172 MOD 10 * 10` , something like that? I am not getting this. Please explain. Thanks

Comment: You query is checking to see if the value in `RXCallDetailId_int` when divided by 10, has a remainder of 10. (In Java, this would be `if (RXCallDetailId_int % 10 == 10) {...}`) Remember when you first learned division in elementary school, how you had remainders instead of decimal places? That's what the `MOD` function does. In the **specific** case of `N MOD 10`, the result is the rightmost digit of `N`.

Comment: I see. Is there a SQL syntax which resembles the one which is used in the query? Because `N MOD M` has only one M , where as my query seems to have two things on the right hand side of `MOD`, namely, `NumberOfResultsThreads` and `CurrModValue`.

Comment: `N MOD M` returns a number, which you're comparing to `CurrModValue` with the equality operator. In other words, `N MOD M = K`. In your case, `N` is a value in your `RXCallDetailId_int` column, `M` is `NumberOfResultsThreads` (10), and `K` is `CurrModValue` (also 10, which is why your result set is empty)